# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} b|\sin(\theta)| \sqrt{a^2\sin^2(\theta) + b^2\cos^2(\theta)} \ d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} b|\sin(\theta)| \sqrt{a^2\sin^2(\theta) + b^2\cos^2(\theta)} \ d\theta$$

I transformed it into:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} b|\sin(\theta)| \sqrt{a^2(1-\cos^2(\theta)) + b^2\cos^2(\theta)} \ d\theta\\ \rightarrow \frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\sin(\theta)| \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2-a^2} + \cos^2(\theta)} \ d\theta$$

Using $u = \cos(\theta)$ I can make the substitution:

$$\frac{-b}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\int_{1}^{0}  \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2-a^2} + u^2} \ du$$

Now I want to use the formula for $\int \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} dx$ but that will give me an expression of $\ln(x)$ I somehow need to end up with :

$$b^2 +\frac{a^2b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a})$$

Does anyone see a route to get this?

Comment: I think what @achillehui is pointing out is that integral should be $0$, not the given expression. Are you sure the question is correct? Should it, perhaps, be an integral from $0$ to $\pi$ instead of $2\pi$?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think the $\sin(\theta)$ terms needs to be absolute valued ....

Comment: For clarity, your question is asking for how to arrive at a formula for $\int\sqrt{u^2+a^2}\,\textrm{d}u$?

Comment: My apologies, no. I am trying to evaluate the top integral. I am explaining my approach (which involves using $\int \sqrt{u^2+a^2}du$)... but this does not work since I need to obtain the last statement (at the bottom)

Comment: If $a^2\gt b^2$, you should use an integral with $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ which should get you what you want.

Comment: @A.RadekMartinez, Is $a^2>b^2$, or the opposite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$F(a,b)=\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin(x)|\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2(x)}\,dx.$$
Symmetry of the integrand gives
$$F(a,b)=4\int_0^{\pi/2}|\sin(x)|\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2(x)}\,dx.$$
For $x\in[0,\pi/2]$, $|\sin x|=\sin x$, so the integral is
$$F(a,b)=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2(x)}\,dx.$$
Then the trick is to assume $a^2>b^2$, then we have
$$F(a,b)=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\sqrt{a^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos^2(x)}\,dx,$$
which is
$$F(a,b)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\sqrt{q^2-\cos^2(x)}\,dx,$$
where $$q=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}.$$
Take $u=\cos x$,
$$F(a,b)=\frac{4q}{a}\int_0^1\sqrt{q^2-u^2}\,du.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $b^2-a^2>0$,

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi} b|\sin(\theta)| \sqrt{a^2(1-\cos^2(\theta)) + b^2\cos^2(\theta)} \ d\theta\\
& =b\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\left[\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(\theta) \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2-a^2} + \cos^2(\theta)} \ d\theta+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \sin(\theta)\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2-a^2} + \cos^2(\theta)} \ d\theta\right]\\
&=b\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\left[-\int_1^{-1}\mathrm{d}x\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2-a^2}+x^2}-\int_{-1}^{0}\mathrm{d}x\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2-a^2}+x^2} \right]\\
&=b\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\int_0^1\mathrm{d}x\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2-a^2}+x^2}\\
&=b\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\left[b+a\log\left(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{a}\right)\right].
\end{align}
$$

The last equality can be safely left to the reader. Using the identity $i \arcsin x = \ln(i x + \sqrt {1 - x^2} )$ we get the expression you wrote in the bottom.